# How to change a background color of jQueryUI Progressbar?

Tags: jquery-ui, background, progress-bar

How to change a background color of jQueryUI Progressbar?

Im trying to use:

`$('#progressbar div').css({backgroundColor: '#9CFF29'});`

but no success :(

Anybody can help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector should be on the main `<div>` so just use `#progressbar` and to override the styling, use just `background` (since it also has an image defined as well), like this:

```
$('#progressbar').css({background: '#9CFF29'});​
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/h6HXm/).

Comment: on this page: http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/ changing neither `#progressbar` nor `#progressbar div` works, because the progress bar loads a background image in addition to the bgcolor, after removing the `background-image`, `#progressbar div` selector is the one that works.

Comment: @aularon - I'm not changing `backgroundColor` in the answer :)  That's why I noted it should be `background`, so it overrides the `background-image` *and* `background-color` properties :)

Comment: Oh, sorry I was busy checking that page and commented quickly. btw how did you get your nickname on jsfiddle? :)

Comment: @aularon - If you're logged in that's how the links are generated, beta will be open for users very soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are selecting the div. Are you able to change other properties of #progressbar such as width?

Answer (score 0):

> jQuery UI Progressbar plugin uses the
>   jQuery UI CSS Framework to style its
>   look and feel, including colors and
>   background textures. We recommend
>   using the ThemeRoller tool to create
>   and download custom themes that are
>   easy to build and maintain.

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/